# Export Salesforce data to external source

Tags: apex, batch

I have a batch job that exports sObjects using some criteria to external service.
To reduce amount of data for sync I sync only objects that have been changed by users since the last sync. To detect such changes I added an additional Datetime field to sObject and update it after every sync.

The criteria:
 `sObject.lastSync__c == null OR sObject.LastModifiedDate > sObject.lastSync__c`  It works fine if there is only one sync process, when I added the second sync process - it changes LastModifiedDate too and that causes extra sync for 1st process.

Is there any other mechanism to detect that sObject have been changed since the last sync?

UPD1: some explanation:
sync process 1 updates:

```
  lastSync1 = 2016-09-30 12-00-00
  LastModifiedDate = 2016-09-30 12-00-00
```

sync process 2 updates:

```
  lastSync2 = 2016-09-30 12-01-00
  LastModifiedDate = 2016-09-30 12-01-00
```

When sync 1 runs on next days it sees that

```
lastSync1 < LastModifiedDate
```

but actually sObject was not updated

UPD2: batch job updates LastModifiedDate , but in accordance to documentation APEX scripts should not update it.

Comment: I would think you need a separate timestamp for each syncing process.

Comment: @adrian-larson I have it, but each process updates LastModifiedDate  (I don't know why, it should be updated after user modification only, not after apex call from batch job). I'm comparing each ts with LastModifiedDate

Comment: Any change to a record sets `LastModifiedDate`. Please link to and quote from any reference you feel says otherwise.

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2014/11/force-com-soql-performance-tips-systemmodstamp-vs-lastmodifieddate-2.html

Comment: Please don't dump this information in the comments, but rather **[edit]** your post. Also, for clarity please quote specifically from the reference what you base your assumption on.

Comment: The `blog` link you reference is being misinterpreted. `LastModifiedDate is automatically updated whenever a user creates or updates the record. LastModifiedDate can be imported with any back-dated value if your business requires preserving original timestamps when migrating data into Salesforce.` includes your batch job because it is running under a context user.  It is not a system process (see: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=When-is-SystemModStamp-different-from-LastModifiedDate&language=en_US)